# Orthonormal sets and inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How do I prove that a given basis $B$ is an orthonormal set relative to a given inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$?

I am unsure if I should use the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt process takes a basis and produces a *new* basis that is orthonormal. It does not help to prove that the original basis is orthonormal. In fact, if the original basis is orthonormal, Gram-Schmidt process "does nothing". To prove that a basis $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ is orthonormal, you need to show that $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle$ is one when $i=j$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: Do you have a use case in mind? Perhaps there's a basis for which you're struggling to calculate some inner products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gram-Schmidt is for taking a set of vectors (usually a basis) and orthonormalizing them. If you want to prove that a given basis is orthonormal, you just need to show that the pairwise inner products of the elements of the basis are zero, and that they each magnitude 1.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that a given basis $B$ is orthonormal, you need to first verify that, for any distinct $x,y\in B$, we have $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, so $B$ is orthogonal. Next you need to verify that, for any $x\in B$, we have $\langle x,x\rangle=1$, so each vector in $B$ is a unit vector.

The Gram-Schmidt process is to convert a given basis into an orthogonal (or orthonormal if you want to) basis which generates the same space.